# select department whose employees salary is more than defined

Tags: mysql

I've one table called "Employees" in database like below:

```
| name    | department | salary |

 ------    -----------  ------

 Divya    HR     500 

 Sumanth  HR     600

 Div      FIN    600

 Sum      FIN    700 

 GD       ENG    700

 MVS      ENG    800
```

+---------+------------+--------+

Now I want to select department whose employees salary is more than 1200.

Result: `FIN(600+700) and ENG(700+800)`

Can any one help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select department,sum(salary)
from Employees
group by department
having sum(salary)>1200
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/973cc/1)**